# How does the Magic Circle ritual work?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

The description of the magic circle ritual includes the following text:

> An affected creature whose level is lower than your Arcana check result minus 10 cannot pass through the circle, affect creatures through the circle’s boundary, or affect the boundary in any way. Other creatures of an affected origin take force damage equal to your Arcana check result when passing through the boundary, but doing so breaks the circle.

What is the difference between `An affected creature` and `Other creatures of an affected origin` in this description? Can creatures of a given origin pass through the circle or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both cases it refers to the **affected creature**: a creature that matches the origin you choose (aberrant, elemental, fey, immortal, natural, shadow, or all) when performing the ritual.

An affected creature whose:

- level is lower than your Arcana check result minus 10:

  > cannot pass through or affect the circle
- level is equal or higher than your Arcana check result minus 10

  > can pass the circle, but takes force damage equal to your Arcana check and breaks the circle as a result

A non-affected creature would be that whose origin does not match the one you specified. The magic circle would not affect them regardless of their level.

Comment: Why "Arcana check result minus 10" ?

Comment: A d20 roll minus 10 averages around 0. Adding your Arcana skill to this causes the affected level to match closely with your Arcana skill.